# PostGIS Split Multipolygon with another Multipolygon

Tags: postgis, splitting

Since PostGIS does not have the ability to split multipolygons by other multipolygons or multilinestrings I found this workaround

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE boundaries AS (
SELECT
  a.statefp as state,
  a.countyfp as countyfp,
  a.name as county,
  a.cd110fp as cd,
  CASE WHEN ST_Within(a.geom, b.geom) THEN a.geom
  ELSE ST_Multi(ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom)) END AS geom
 FROM us_cd2008 b
JOIN countyparts2008_with_cd a ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom));

CREATE TEMP TABLE boundaries2 AS (
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT state, cd, countyfp, county, (ST_DUMP(b.geom)).geom FROM boundaries b) as temp
   WHERE ST_GeometryType(temp.geom) = 'ST_Polygon');

CREATE TABLE countyparts2008_split_v2 AS (
SELECT ST_Multi(ST_Union(geom)) AS geom,
     state,
     cd,
     countyfp,
     county
   FROM boundaries2
   GROUP BY cd, countyfp, county, state);
```

However the ouput looks like this...
[image]

Not sure how to fix it so that postgis doesn't include those lines towards the bottom. Any idea?